# turn closed captioning button off for streaming videos (m3u8 file) on ios

Tags: ios, video

I'm having this one my page

```
<video>
  <source type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.4d0028, mp4a.40.5';" src="xxxxx.m3u8">
  </source>
</video>
```

since I'm using m3u8, the closed captioning button will automatically show up by default.

Below link is exactly the issue

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1801/_index.html

and according to this:

iOS 7 also supports a CLOSED-CAPTIONS attribute for the EXT-X-STREAM-INF tag. You can declare the absence of closed caption content in the playlist by specifying CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE on the EXT-X-STREAM-INF tag. The "Unknown CC" option as shown in Figure 1 will not be displayed in the selection when the absence of closed caption content is declared.

I need to set CLOSED-CAPTIONS to none, but the problem is I'm not sure where to set it from my html, I've tried something like

```
<video>
  <source type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.4d0028, mp4a.40.5'; closed-captions=none" src="xxxxx.m3u8">
  </source>
</video>
```

didn't work though.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using Javascript you can control the captions

in the sample below I'm using jQuery (because my page was already using it) but you can do the same without that. I also target a specific ID for my `<video>` element, imaginatively called "video", and I also include controls on there to pause/seek the video `<video id="video" controls>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var video = document.querySelector('#video'); // get the video element
    var tracks = video.textTracks; // one for each track element
    var track = tracks[0]; // corresponds to the first track element
    track.mode = 'hidden';
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Sorry for getting back late, just got the time to verify it.